# Convert mysql data into human readable format

Tags: php, mysql

How do I convert this date `2014-05-09 00:00:00` into `2014-may-09` in PHP ??

Comment: Some simple google search would ve solved it.i think.
date('Y-M-d',strtotime('2014-05-09 00:00:00')); http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php

Comment: For mysql [demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/37441)

Comment: `date("Y-M-d",strtotime("2014-05-09 00:00:00"));`   refer [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) for different format characters.

Comment: @NabinKunwar i just spent 2 hours on a 'simple google search'. This is the first page that gives me a REAL USABLE answer. Not everyone is a pro programmer...

Comment: @jameswalker It's not about being pro programmer, Its just about learning to search right. Anyway glad you found solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with

```
 echo date('Y-M-d',strtotime('2014-05-09 00:00:00'));
```

For reference [strtotime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Answer (score 7):

### Using PHP

Use the [`DateTime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class:

```
$d = new DateTime('2014-05-09 00:00:00');
echo $d->format('Y-M-d');
```

This will produce `2014-May-09`. If you need the month to be in lowercase, run the string through [`strtolower()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php) or [`mb_strtolower()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strtolower.php).

### Using MySQL

Alternatively, format the date in the query so that it returns the desired format. Use the MySQL [`DATE_FORMAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function for this. The format you are looking for is `%Y-%b-$d`.

Comment: This should be desired answer.

Answer (score 1):

**You can try some thing like this**

```
$data="2014-05-09 00:00:00";
$datetime = strtotime( $data);
$formatedDate = date("Y-M-d", $datetime);
```

I hope this what you are asking for!

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

try `date()`

```
$d = '2014-05-09 00:00:00';
echo date('Y-M-d', strtotime($d)); //2014-May-09
```